# Form Response with multiple values in a single cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms

Many forms that have multiple choice questions. Many form apps (definitely Google Forms and JotForm) (when integrated with sheets) put them all in one cell sometimes delimited with a `,` , `;` or with a new line.

This makes it very hard to analyze the data, since it is treated as the one answer.

Here is a sample of a form with it's responses:
[Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdWjduHRgu4CLqdztJGn_5Sh-tjX--Kks5Z3CFHJew9AYUG8A/viewform?usp=sf_link), [Responses](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eCV2Z1fD_0oW1K7-WG1Vt5hZwIMIGTdjz-YPz4A0XBQ/edit#gid=490369797).

The goal is to separate each entry by name and date. (See "Desired output" tab in responses). It should be a solution in sheets, since editing the form is not always an option (I have come across this issue with many form's data).

It has to be dynamic (as the responses come in) and support an indefinite amount of entries. Also preferably not use a custom function.

Responses:
[image: Responses]

Desired Output:

[image: Desired Output]

I posted my answer with its shortcomings.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with, it is not really good because it uses a custom function (I am having trouble using it the data it outputs with another sheet using import range). I also feel like it is really long way to do something that should be simpler to achieve.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Split(QUERY(joinSplit(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER({","&{'Form Responses 1'!C2:C}},{'Form Responses 1'!C2:C}<>""),",",Filter({"‍"&{'Form Responses 1'!B2:B}&"‍"&{'Form Responses 1'!A2:A}&"‍"},{'Form Responses 1'!C2:C}<>""))), "‍"),"Select Col1 where Col1 is not null"),"‍"))
```

Here is the custom function "joinSplit" code (I got it from somewhere but I cant remember where):

```
`function joinSplit(column, delim)
{
  var result = [];
  var row = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = column.length; i < l; i++)
  {
    row = column[i].join(delim).split(delim);
    row.forEach( function(elt) { result.push([elt]); } ); 
  }  
  return result;
}`
```

If anyone wants, [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F6mZsjYcaVfqHEAyhrlpZqvZ4ZcVzsPDlHW5eL2XubY/edit?pli=1#gid=1095663540) is a ready to use version, make a copy and change the appropriate fields.

Comment: What is this? If this does not solve your issue, do not put it as an answer. Answers should only be correct solutions. Remove this and edit your original question.

Comment: This is a partial solution because it uses a custom function and as I stated in the question I **prefer** a non script solution . I posted it because if there is no other answer, this might be useful to someone else. Should I remove it?

Comment: If it's a workaround for your issue, then you can leave it like that. I'm afraid there is no User interface solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not change question in the form? like earlier it was (as an example I am using Google Forms)

[Old Version of Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rwd8d.png)

but now can you change it to:

[New version of Question with Multiple Choice grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faL4X.png)

This way, your responses when collected in the sheet will have a simple Yes/No for each fruit which can be easily analysed without asking users to answer more questions.

Later you can have a dynamic list of users who prefer a particular fruit with date shown using a `Filter()` function.

Comment: I updated the question to make it clear why this wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60861/google-sheets-split-multi-line-cell-into-new-rows-duplicate-surrounding-row-e) is a solution I found on web apps SE, to a very similar question.

It uses a custom function though.

```
function result(range) {
  delimiter = ", "
  targetColumn = 2

  var output2 = [];
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][targetColumn].split(delimiter);    
    for(var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      var output1 = []; 
      for(var k=0, kLen=range[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
        if(k == targetColumn) {
          output1.push(s[j]);
        } else {
          output1.push(range[i][k]);
        }
      }
      output2.push(output1);
    }    
  }
  return output2;
}
```